# Retrieving Value of the <TD> in the selected row

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Given the following code below, how can I have it modified such that it will alert me back what is the value in the first column of any of the selected rows?

i.e. selected row is number two, so, alert("oranges")

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

var x = '<table id="mstrTable" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100">\n'
      + '<tr><td>Apples</td><td>Carrots</td></tr><tr><td>Oranges</td><td>Celery</td></tr>\n'
      + '</table>\n' 
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = x
var color = "#E1E0D7"
var rows = document.getElementById("mstrTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
var n = rows.length;
var bgcs = [];
for(var i=0; i<n; ++i) bgcs[i] = rows[i].style.backgroundColor;

function changeColor(e) {
if(!e) e = window.event;
var o = e.target? e.target: e.srcElement;
while(o.tagName && o.tagName.toLowerCase()!="tr") o = o.parentNode;
    for(var i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    rows[i].style.backgroundColor = bgcs[i];
    if(rows[i]==o) rows[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}//end of function

if(document.addEventListener) for(var i=0; i<n; ++i) rows[i].addEventListener("click", changeColor, false);
else for(var i=0; i<n; ++i) rows[i].attachEvent("onclick", changeColor);

}//end of onload()
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Go back and accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: If you wrote all of that yourself, then it should be a simple modification. If you didn't, then I suggest you try doing it yourself so you can learn from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rows = document.getElementById("mstrTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
function getFirstCol(row){
    alert(row.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML);
}
// Example usage
getFirstCol(rows[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the children of the `tr` node when you change the color.

```
if(rows[i]==o) {
    rows[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    console.log(rows[i].children[0])
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uwzKg/1/)